# Find the remainder of the division of $P(x)$ with $(x-3)$ if $P(x+2)=2x^3-4x^2+2x+3$

Tags: polynomials

I found that $P(x+2)$ is $2x^3+8x^2+10x+7$, what should I do next?
I don't know how t find $P(x)$

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Why the subscript $1$ in the title version of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(3)=P(1+2)=2\cdot1^3-4\cdot1^2+2\cdot1+3=3$

Just in case you need for any other thing:

$P(x)=P((x-2)+2)=2(x-2)^3-4(x-2)^2+2(x-2)+3$, and expand if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x-3$ is linear, the remainder will be a constant. You will have $$P(x)=(x-3)\cdot Q(x)+C$$ so you can find that $C$ just by plugging in $x=3$. Note that you will not need to know anything about $Q(x)$ or $Q(3)$.

Comment: I don't know how to find P(x)

Comment: But you know $P(x+2)=2x^3-4x^2+2x+3$. So $P(x)=2(x-2)^3-4(x-2)^2+2(x-2)+3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$P(x)=P(3)+(x-3)P'(3)+\dfrac{(x-3)^2}{2!}P''(3)+\ldots$